# How can I create a bomb countdown timer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a Unity game which uses bombs and explosions. I want to limit the player to being able to plant only 1 bomb every 3 seconds, the first bomb will explode and then the player can plant another, the timer that I created for this does not seem to be working.

When I play the game the player can plant a bomb but is not able to plant anymore bombs after waiting more than 3 seconds. Is my time logic correct for this?

```
public class CombatController : MonoBehaviour {

    //public GameObject enemy;
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject Bomb;
    public GameObject Explosion;
    public int timer = 0;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        BombKeyPress ();   //Check if the user wants to plant the bomb.     
    }


    //Method BombKeyPress - This method will activate logic for our bombkeypress.
    public void BombKeyPress ()
    {

        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) {
            BombDrop ();

        }

    }

    //Method BombDrop - This method will instantiate our bomb.
    private void BombDrop () 
    {
        //If the timer is not counting, allow the player to drop another.
        if (Bomb && timer <=0) {
            Instantiate (Bomb, this.gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity); //Make New Bombs
            timer = 3; //Set our bomb timer to 3 seconds.

            //Countdown our bombtimer.
            for (int i = 3; i <= 0; i--) {
                timer = i;
                print(i);
            }

            //BombExplosion(); //Now blow up our bomb

        }   

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `Time` class. It's pretty simple.

Declare two variables `BombRate` and `NextBombTime` like below:

```
[SerializeField]
private float BombRate=0.5f;// Tweak to value to your requirement.
private float NextBombTime=0f;
```

So, in your Bomb function, you could have something like this:

```
void Bomb (){
if(Time.time>NextBombTime){
NextBombTime=Time.time+BombRate;
//Do your bomb stuff here
}
}
```

You can also use Coroutines if you like.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That is much better than what I had, and it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a coroutine to detonate the bomb, so you can write something like:

```
//public GameObject enemy;
[SerializeField]
public GameObject Bomb;
public GameObject Explosion;
public float timer = 0;

private float currentTime;
private bool canBomb = true;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
        BombKeyPress ();   //Check if the user wants to plant the bomb.   
}
IEnumerator BombExplosionTimer()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
    BombExplosion();
    canBomb = true;
}

public void BombExplosion()
{

    //Put your Bomb explosion logic here
}


//Method BombKeyPress - This method will activate logic for our bombkeypress.
public void BombKeyPress ()
{

    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) && canBomb) {
        canBomb = false;
        BombDrop ();
        StartCoroutine(BombExplosionTimer());
    }
}



//Method BombDrop - This method will instantiate our bomb.
public void  BombDrop () 
{
    //If the timer is not counting, allow the player to drop another.

        Instantiate (Bomb, this.gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity); //Make New Bombs
        timer = 3; //Set our bomb timer to 3 seconds.

}
```

Comment: You don't `need` to use it but it's a valid option ;)